Trying to add energy to a moving gear through pushing
I want to make a mechanism where by simply pushing some sort of button, I can accelerate a gear. I haven't been able to find anything online because I can't think of any applications where it might be used. For example, in an engine, the crankshaft is accelerated only when the piston reaches the top of the cylinder, at which point it is pushed down using combustion. However, I want to be able to accelerate the gear at any time through a pushing force.
Below is a diagram of what I would like it to look like. Pushing the yellow button would cause the blue axle to rotate. However, even after the button is pressed, the axle should continue rotating freely (of course it may slow down due to small amount of friction). But, whenever the button is pressed again, the axle should accelerate.

The youtube channel where I found the above diagram converts one button push into one 360 degree rotation but after that the axle stops rotating. But of course that's not what I want. Do you guys think its possible to create something like this?

You want a combination of a screw and a freewheel.
Didn't you ever have a toy top that had a handle on top that you used to "pump up" its speed?

source of picture

Thanks a lot! I have never seen a toy like this actually :/

Showing my age, I guess :-) These were common around the middle of the previous century!

It's already said in the older answer by Dave Tweed that you can convert linear pushing to rotation by having  a steep enough thread. As well one could apply something like the crankshaft in a motor. Bicycles are based on the same idea.
As you probably have noticed, the biker can stay still and let he bike roll freely. That's based on the tooth mechanism in the rear hub of the bike. See it for example by watching a bike freehub repair tutorial video like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhY0XkdUi5c
The same mechanical idea, of course, can be used in the toy shown in the older answer - the rotation can go on at the end of the push, as you wanted. And you can pull the knob up and increase the rotation speed by pushing faster.
Faster? Using something presented above really needs faster movements to get more speed when there's already built up some speed. That can be a problem, if you want to build up the speed with equal speed pushes.
One solution is to have a gearbox and that can be automatic like in advanced car transmission systems. Another possibility is to use the pushes to generate electricity or pressure and let it do the actual rotating work. In theory  you could simply pump air. If the air stream from the output nozzle is tangential with the rotating wheel it builds up speed without a need to pump faster at higher speeds. That's true if there's no friction, but in practice it's only a dream. In addition every energy form conversion causes losses that do not occur in direct mechanical transmission like in bikes.

Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about a bike and the fact that the wheels don't drive the pedals :/. I will definitely research more about freehubs.
